# For loop to pass variable onto function

Tags: jquery, loops, css-selectors

```
$(function () {
    $max = 4;
    $i = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $('#itemListLeading table tr :nth-child(' + $i + ')').each(function () {
            $length = $(this).children().text().length;
            if ($length > $max) {
                $max = $length;
            }
            $('#itemListLeading table tr :nth-child(' + $i ' +)').promise().done(function () {
                $(this).css("min-width", $max * 8 + "px");
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Not sure why this here doesn't work. I'm trying to pass '1' and '2' and maybe more later to the nth-child(). It works on a single nth-child(1), ie. without the for loop. Or is there a better way of passing x amount of variables to run through the function?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xNquz/7/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xNquz/7/  link here as it wouldn't let me post it.

Comment: JavaScript isn't PHP; your variable names don't _need_ start with `$`.

Comment: You haven't really explained what the problem is.

Comment: @Matt Ok yeah, I was just testing to see if it would work with that.

Comment: @Felix Kling If you go on the js.fiddle it should be a bit clearer I'm trying to pass the number's 1 and 2 to the function so I can make it work for nth-child(1) and nth-child(2), without just copying the function out again and replacing 1 with 2.

Comment: No, the demo does not really help me. You said *"Not sure why this here doesn't work."*, but what exactly does not work? What do you expect to happen and what does actually happen?

Comment: I expect the td child2 and 3 to be sized accordingly '$max * 8' which is why I added in the loop to try to pass those 2 numbers. If you paste this in to replace the script it works for one td row and I want it to work for the next 1.

Comment: $(function(){
   $max = 4;

$('#itemListLeading table tr :nth-child(2)').each(function() {
  $length = $(this).children().text().length;
    if ($length > $max){
        $max = $length;   
    }
    $('#itemListLeading table tr :nth-child(2)').promise().done(function() {
          $(this).css("min-width", $max * 8 + "px");
    });        
});
 });

Answer (score 0):

You've got a syntax error in your script:

```
$(function () {
    $max = 4;
    $i = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $('#itemListLeading table tr :nth-child(' + $i + ')').each(function () {
            $length = $(this).children().text().length;
            if ($length > $max) {
                $max = $length;
            }
            // Old line
            //$('#itemListLeading table tr :nth-child(' + $i ' +)').promise().done(function () {

            $('#itemListLeading table tr :nth-child(' + $i + ')').promise().done(function () {
                $(this).css("min-width", $max * 8 + "px");
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Ah yeah thanks. Seems to kind execute atleast now but crashes my browser and asks me to stop the script. Is it just getting stuck in loop?